# Find out if a persistent sqlalchemy mapped object was modified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to find out if a persistent sqlalchemy mapped object was modified?

It means I recieve a object (persistent, with identiy) from the database.
Then the user (maybe!) modify its data in a dialog-window.

Is there a way to find out if the object in memory/RAM was modified compared to its instance in the database itself? I don't want to compare each attribute against the data in the dialog-window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=is_modified#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.is_modified)

```
session = sqlalchemy.orm.Session.object_session(model)
session.is_modified(model)
```